# Need some advice for trying to mock a .NET WebClient or equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq, webclient

I've got some code which downloads some RSS feeds.

I've been using `WebClient` or `Argotic.Syndication.RssFeed` libraries.

**But these aren't mockable :(**

I definately do not want to hit the real RSS feed every time I run the unit test.

Does anyone have any suggestions to what I can do?

Do I need to create an evil wrapper? If so .. suggestions on this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I go for creating a wrapper for every external dependency (if it's practical). So, every interaction with the filesystem/a webservice/database should be done through an interface only, which will lead to more testable code.

Another solution of course is (as always) [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page).

Answer (score 23):

> Does anyone have any suggestions to what I can do?

Abstract the actual HTTP call behind an interface. Then write an implmentation of this interface using WebClient. Now have your main class take this interface as dependency. You could now mock this interface in the unit test and configure your dependency injection framework inject the correct implementation at runtime.

Comment: Agree with you. Example: [Mocking System.Net.WebClient](http://brunov.info/blog/2013/07/30/tdd-mocking-system-net-webclient/).