# How to integration-test the `WebClient`

Tags: c#, integration-testing, webclient

Please note that I've already went through these answers:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608983/how-to-verify-test-webclient-usage), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095557/need-some-advice-for-trying-to-mock-a-net-webclient-or-equivalent).

those answers helped implementing a **WebClientSimulator** successfully (by the help of: [WebClient interface example](http://brunov.info/blog/2013/07/30/tdd-mocking-system-net-webclient/)).

I need to test an automatic web page notification based on url and some parameters, But I don't know how to use the WebClientSimulator correctly:

```
public void NotifyWebPage(string url, NameValueCollection parameters)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri(url), parameters);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Validate_My_NotifyWebPage()
{
    string url = "https://www.someurl.com/";
    NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

    NotifyWebPage(url, parameters);
}
```

How do i verify that the web page was notified? with the given parameters?

Comment: So you'd like to implement the WebClient interface example, as it looks like the right solution here, but you don't know how?

Comment: Iv'e already implemented the WebClient interface (its the same as in the link so i didn't copied it to my question), now my problem is to implement the TestMethod.

Comment: You cannot **unit**-test this method. You can only do an **integration**-test on that. If you want to have a **unit**-test, then you have to redesign the class/method.

Comment: @Sir Rufo what do you mean by integration-test

Comment: There is a huge difference between **unit**- and **integration**-test. They both looks equal but have different impacts. **integration**-tests need a special environment, where **unit**-tests work without any. Thats why it is called **unit**-test, you test only a small unit

Comment: @Sir Rufo you are right, i need the integration-test (updated the question)

Comment: As a suggestion, I would inject a WebClient instance (or an interface) into the class to make the class ready for unit-testing, but you should know that already from the WebClient interface example link